# Google App engine setting up proxy with reactjs app displays reactJS app instead of routing to API

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, proxy

I am deploying my reactjs using `http-proxy-middlewear` in `google cloud app engine`. My API is hosted in api endpoint of google. It is displaying CORS when I try to access it via direct url. So I am setting up proxy.
Proxy is working fine in my dev machine, when I do `node server.js` but when I deploy the app to GCP, it displays the reactJS app fine, but for api, it is not routing them to my server.js (I believe) since the api urls are not returning the response, and when I put them in browser, my reactJS app is being displayed.

So if my app engine url is: `https://app-engine-url` and I try to access API, `https://app-engine-url/api/get_first_api` (it still displays the reactjs app instead of displaying me json response with my API data)

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

// Add a proxy to forward requests to your Google Endpoints API
app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'https://my-google-api-endpoint', // Replace with your Google Endpoints API domain
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': '' // Replace '/api' with an empty string to remove the prefix
  }
}));

  

// Serve the React app from the build directory (make sure to build your React app first)
app.use(express.static('build'));

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs14
service: reactjs-withproxy

handlers:

  # Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$

  # Catch all handler to index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch:
  - url: "/api/*"
    service: reactjs-withproxy
```

Comment: As per the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#example:~:text=%23%20Send%20any%20domain/sub%2Ddomain%20with%20a%20path%20that%20starts%20with%20%E2%80%9Cwork%E2%80%9D%20to%20the%20static%20backend%20service.%0A%2D%20url%3A%20%22*/work*%22%0A%C2%A0%20service%3A%20static%2Dbackend) can you try changing the `dispatch.yaml` url as follows `- url: "*/api*"`.

Comment: it didn't worked either. I ended up creating another short app which acts like a proxy and hosted it on a new service.

Comment: From the above comment, I assume that your problem has been solved. Can you share your solution as an answer so that it will help others too?